# Bigcommerce API authentication and debugging

Tags: php, html, api, debugging, bigcommerce

here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bigcommerce API</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        include('bigcommerce.php');

        use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce;

        Bigcommerce::configure(array(
        'store_url' => 'https://xxx.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/',
        'username'  => 'admin',
        'api_key'   => 'xxx'
        ));

        $ping = Bigcommerce::getTime();
        if ($ping) echo $ping->format('H:i:s');
        echo('hello');
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I run this and nothing happens. I look in the browser and it shows no errors. How do I even begin to debug?

**EDIT**

I took out /api/v2 and now I am seeing this error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/bigcommerce.php:404 Stack trace: #0 /Library/WebServer/Documents/bigcommerce.php(404): DateTime->__construct('@1418752201') #1 /Library/WebServer/Documents/index.php(19): Bigcommerce\Api\Client::getTime() #2 {main} thrown in /Library/WebServer/Documents/bigcommerce.php on line 404

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I added the following to index.php and it works!

```
if( ! ini_get('date.timezone') )
{
    date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
}
```

Comment: Add error reporting at the top of your file: `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>` Also you don't even see the hello?

Comment: I see the hello, sorry I wasn't clear about that. I also added the error reporting and nothing shows. If I change the URL to something bogus, I get an error. But AS IS, no errors.

Comment: Do you have correct values to configure it ? And your url must not contain the part "/api/v2" as it is automatically putted in the class. Ref https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php/blob/master/bigcommerce.php#L297

Comment: I took /api/v2 out and made edits to the original post with what I see now.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following to index.php and it works!

```
if( ! ini_get('date.timezone') )
{
    date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
}
```

– LanterneRouge